# Illegal assignment from Id to List Error?

Tags: apex, list

> I am getting an error like duplicate iD.
>   Wrapperlist is a List of contact

```
    id taskId = '00T****005ezShPEAU';
    list<task> updateTask = new list<task>();
    Type idArrType = Type.forName('List<string>');
    List<string> wrapperList = (List<string>) JSON.deserialize(getSelectedContact, idArrType);
    for(string lst :wrapperList){
        Task taskObj = new Task(id=taskId);
        updateTask.add(new Task(
            whoid =lst,
            id=taskObj.id
        ));
    }
    update updateTask;
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You cannot set multiole WhoId, Try to set something like this: ```if (wrapperList.size() > 0) {getTask.WhoId = wrapperList[0];}```

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova I need set list of who id to a particular task ID

Comment: Yes you cannot set list to single Id, may be you need to create separate task for each whoid.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question a little more.if your wrapperlist is contains list of contacts then storing it in list<String> will cause problem while accessing contacts other attribute.

Comment: @ranjitMishra It is not causing problem. I need to assign multiple contacts to a single task.

Comment: @SFKID post your complete code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To associate multiple Contacts to one Task, your Salesforce org *must* have [Shared Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_enable_shared_activities.htm) turned on. This will allow you to link up to 50 Contacts to a single Task. Without this feature active, you may associated only one Contact to a Task.

With Shared Activities, `WhoId` remains a single field - you can't assign a list to it unless you're using the SOAP API. To associate multiple Contacts to the Task, you'd need to write code to create [`TaskRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm) objects, where the `RelationId` field is the Contact's Id, and the `TaskId` field is the Task's Id.